# Set-Cookie in Chromecast Network

Tags: javascript, cookies, chromecast

We observed an issue that the set-cookie headers (returned by our server in HTTP Response Headers) are dropped/ignored by our ChromeCast receiver. We are able to observe them if we proxy the network traffic using tools like Charles. We also observed that the cookies work if they are setup via code (JS).

Has anyone observed the same? Any alternatives around this?

Is this limitation of ChromeCast support?

Searched quite a lot but no real evidence of this.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392293/chromecast-receiver-app-cookies) can help you